# Mathematica: ListLinePlot & RegionFunction - a bug or a documentation issue?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

The doc for `RegionFunction` states:

[image]

However, `RegionFunction` is not mentioned in the doc for `ListLinePlot`.
Trying to use it:

[image]

So, it seems a doc issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting find.  It looks like something that was on the board but never got implemented.

Comment: @Mr. That reminds me of the Chinese curse "May you live in interesting times" :)

Comment: Good find, looks like a documentation bug. It must be a very complicated state machine they have at WRI to sort all these options. There are 1000's of them. There is also dependency between options. For example, including one option, can affect if another option is used or not. Here is an example: Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,Pi},FrameLabel->{{1,2},{3,4}}] now the FrameLabel has no effect, but command is evaluated and FrameLabel quietly ignored (a warning would be nice!). Now add Frame->True, now FrameLabel is used. +1 for the find.
--Nasser

Comment: @belisaius: Congrats on 20k! You can now retire :)

Comment: @yoda Thanks! I am really thinking about that ...

Comment: I was going to agree with you that its a doc issue (since you can call ListLinePlot[Select[Table[...],#[[2]]<.5&]), but if you do that I think you get a line connecting the gap where Sin[x]>0.5. So I think this is a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's a bug, in the documentation.  Supporting `RegionFunction` in `List(Line)Plot` would be a good feature addition, however.  (Please email support@wolfram.com.)

---

One workaround would be to replace points that are "out of bounds" with `None`:

```
ListLinePlot[
 Function[{w, y}, If[y < 0.5, {w, y}, None]] @@@ 
  Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}]]
```

Comment: Thanks @Brett. Does `None` have any advantage over `Null` or any other NaN?

Comment: Nope.  I don't think I'd use `Null` since that can come up naturally in lists due to other reasons (adjacent commas, etc...), which might confuse someone if the data gets used somewhere else for some reason.